# how to pull variable out of clickListener for use in another clickListener

Tags: android

what i'm trying to do is have a list of platforms for the user to choose from. by clicking a platform it puts in the name of the corresponding sql table name in a variable. but i can't figure out how to use that variable in my submit buttons clickListener. here is the section of code i am working with.

```
String platformText;

platform.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id)
   {
     String temp;

       if(position == 1)
       {
            temp = "ps3games";
       }
       else if(position == 2)
       {
            temp = "xbox360games";
       }
    }
});
platformText = temp;        

    submitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
     public void onClick(View v)
     {
             addProduct(platformText)
         }
    });
```

i've cut out code not essential to the question.

Comment: moving "platformText = temp" up 1 line into the setOnItemClickListener and outside the onItemClick gives me a "Syntax error on token "=", delete this token" error. i think this might be the solution but this error makes no sense at all. and a project clean does not fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
String platformText;

platform.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        String temp;

        if(position == 1)
        {
            temp = "ps3games";
        }
        else if(position == 2)
        {
            temp = "xbox360games";
        }
        platformText = temp; 
      }
 });

submitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
     public void onClick(View v)
     {
         addProduct(platformText)
     }
});
```

You needed to set `platformTitle=temp` within your `onClickListener`, you were doing that outside of it before.

Comment: that gives the "Cannot refer to a non-final variable platformText inside an inner class defined in a different method" error. which is what i am trying to work around.

Comment: Have you tried making `platformText` public? Does that change anything?

Comment: public String platformText gives "Illegal modifier for parameter platformText; only final is permitted"

Comment: declare `public String platformText;` at the start of your class, not within the method. What does that say?

Comment: lols of course put it at the start. that did it. thank you sir. /salute

Comment: You're very welcome! Glad to help. Upvote and acceptance appreciated :)

Comment: note: making platformText public made the temp variable pointless so for people who stumble upon this question be aware that you can use the public variable instead of the temp variable.